# Communicate data between C and Python apps running continuously

Tags: python, c, interprocess, inter-process-communicat

Is there a way to pass data between continuously running C program and continuously running Python program? It is crucial that C program starts first.

So far I have (for C side):

```
void run_cmd(char *cmd[])
{
    int parentID = getpid();
    char str[1*sizeof(double)];
    sprintf(str, "%d", parentID);
    char* name_with_extension;
    name_with_extension = malloc(2+strlen(cmd[1])+1*sizeof(int)+1);
    strcat(name_with_extension, cmd[1]);
    strcat(name_with_extension, " ");
    strcat(name_with_extension, str);

    pid_t pid;
    char *argv[] = {"sh", "-c", name_with_extension, NULL};
    int status;
    //printf("Run command: %s\n", cmd);
    status = posix_spawn(&pid, "/bin/sh", NULL, NULL, argv, environ);
    if (status == 0) {
        //printf("Child pid: %i\n", pid);
        //printf("My process ID : %d\n", getpid());

        //if (waitpid(pid, &status, 0) != -1) {
        //    printf("Child exited with status %i\n", status);
        //} else {
        //    perror("waitpid");
        //}

        //part below is not tested and will probably not work
        int myout[2];
        pipe(myout);
        int status;
        int ch;
        do {
            if (read(myout[0], &ch, 1)>0){
                write(1, &ch, 1);
            }
            waitpid(pid, &status, WNOHANG);
        } while (!WIFEXITED(status) && !WIFSIGNALED(status));

    }
}
```

For Python, I can only get the arguments list for now using:

```
print 'Arguments ', str(sys.argv)
```

As I understand from documentation, ***subprocess.Popen*** is not a way to go, since it creates a new process, which I do not want.

***Embedding*** C in Python (or inverse) is not an option as code is too big.

I thought using process ***IDs*** and possibly ***sockets*** communicating data between, but not sure and need some advice.

The aim is to accomplish this in ***Windows***, but unified single implementation would be better.

Comment: You have *undefined behavior* in your code, the `malloc` function doesn't initialize the memory it allocates, so when you call `strcat` it will look for the string terminator which may not be inside the allocated memory and you might write out of bounds of the allocated memory.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg the code is just used for testing. If important, the program is run as follows: ./c_prog ./py_prog, where py_prog, when started, receives port number of the parent

Comment: @MocialovBoris fix what you already know to be wrong, (because of what Joachim posted), else it may screw up your future debugging.  As for 'Is there a way to pass data between continuously running C program and continuously running Python program?', then sure, of course there is.

Comment: @MartinJames oh, I missed answers like that

Comment: Another option are file system based FIFO queues.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer i find FIFO queues simple and they achieve the task, thank you. I have only one question, what is the difference between FIFO queues and a simple usage of files

Comment: @MocialovBoris While a FIFO is a file system construct, a file is more of a permanent resource.  For example, if your program were to exit and you were using a file, you would need to scan through the file to figure out where you left off.  Using a FIFO, you could simply restart and your code could pick up where it left off since the only stuff in the queue is the stuff that you have not processed yet.  Make sense?

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options

1. Pass data through stdin and output to stdout.

You'll have to devise a line-based format, read a line from stdin and print what you want to communicate to parent process.

See the example below

2. Use an IPC mechanism for process communication

In this I'd propose using zmq. It's cross-platform and has quite a few features.

So, a bit of code in python showing the general idea with stdin/stdout communication

### P1 (the child)

```
import sys                             
import time                            
i=0                                    
while True:                            
    line = sys.stdin.readline().strip()
    if not line:                       
        time.sleep(0.5)                

    if line=="ping":                   
        sys.stdout.write("pong\n")     
        sys.stdout.flush()             
        i+= 1                          

    if i > 10:                         
        sys.stdout.write("exit\n")     
        sys.stdout.flush()
```

### P2 (the master)

```
import subprocess                                                                             

p = subprocess.Popen(['python', './p1.py'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)     
while True:                                                                                   
    p.stdin.write("ping\n")                                                                   
    p.stdin.flush()                                                                           
    ret = p.stdout.readline().strip()                                                         
    print ret                                                                                 
    if ret=='exit':                                                                           
        exit(0)
```

P2 starts P1, they do 10 ping-pongs and p1 notifies p2 that it must kill itself. The processes can be long running.

Comment: By stdin and stdout you mean smth like that: "ifconfig | grep en0", right? Then I do not know how this can be scaled up to continuously running programs.

Comment: @MocialovBoris, I'll post an example in a bit

Comment: @MocialovBoris Both are in python as I am not sure about the windows way of doing things, but in c it would be something similar.

Comment: Thank you for you advice, but I have found FIFO queues simple and straightforward