# Subprocess module Python

Tags: python, multiprocessing, subprocess

We have an issue using the subprocess library in Python. We tried to pass 2 message with the function communicate. The first one work correctly, but the second one generates a IOError
error. I think that we probably use incorrectly the function of the subprocess library, but we are not able to fix it.
Can anyone help us?
Here is the code:

```
from subprocess import *

video=Popen("omxplayer myvideo.mp4",shell=True,stdout=PIPE,stdin=PIPE)

video.stdin.write('+')
video.stdin.flush()
result=video.stdout.read()
print "Vol +: "+result
video.communicate('p')
print "Pause"
```

And the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "youtube.py", line 55, in <module>
    proc.stdin.write('+')
IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

Thank you

Comment: Popen.communicate waits for the process to finish, so when you try the second call, the process is already dead.

Comment: So, is it correct using the functions write(), flush() and read()?

Comment: Yep. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30241937/communicate-data-between-c-and-python-apps-running-continuously/30242613#30242613